# Picture Library Slideshow

Tags: 2013, web-part, picture-library

I've added one Picture Library Slideshow web part to my home page of our SharePoint 2013 team site. But I don't like the appearance of this web part (for example size of pictures, next Pause icons ,  ...)

How can I customize the appearance of my web part?

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the icons, you could either edit the webpart and deselect "Show Toolbar" or you could add this to a CEWP or a Script Editor Web part to hide those pesky buttons.

```
<style type="text/css">

.ms-WPBody a[onclick ^= "Next"]{
display:none;
        }
.ms-WPBody a[onclick ^= "Play"]{
display:none;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you user19952 but i want to display these buttons but in small size, i mean i just have problem with their size!

Comment: Well, the size of the icons/buttons are set by the size of the pictures.. /_layouts/15/images/plprev1.gif, plpause1, plnext1. So you could try to fiddle around with those in a test environment.

Comment: Thank you again but in code below there is an answer but i don't know how to use it                                          http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60797/how-to-center-a-picture-library-slideshow-web-parts-previous-next-and-pause-b/60892#60892

Comment: I can't help you as i tend to work with C# and Administration, i don't know javascript or Jquery. Sorry.

Comment: ooops! thank you...

Comment: @Milad to use the answer in the link, simply add a content editor web part to the page, edit its source, and copy/paste that code into it (place it in a `<script>` tag first).

Answer (score 1):

For the Picture Library Slideshow web part in SP 2013, there is a check box `Show Toolbar` as displayed in the image below. Uncheck it to hide the next, previous, and pause controls.

[image]